# Redirect www to non www in Route53 and CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53, cname

I'm using CloudFront with S3 as origin (the bucket is NOT public, static website is NOT enabled). The bucket has some random name.

I've created an ACM and R53 entree for example.com + configured CloudFront for this domain and it works fine for https://example.com.

Now I want to redirect https://www.example.com to https://example.com.
I added [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) as domain to CloudFront (not sure if it's needed) and I created a new R53 entree (CNAME) from [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) to example.com.

Now both domain.com and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) work but this is not what I want. I want [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) to redirect to example.com. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use CloudFront Functions to redirect based on the host header. You can create the function in the **Functions** section of the CloudFront console - here's an example:

```
function handler(event) {
    var request = event.request;
    var host = request.headers.host.value;

    if (host === 'www.example.com') {    
        var response = {
            statusCode: 301,
            statusDescription: 'Moved Permanently',
            headers: { 
                'location': { "value": `https://example.com${request.uri}` } 
            }
        };

        return response;
    }

    return request;
}
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. I think as someone else pointed out. Redirection is http layer not DNS so this approach is correct for people who truly want to redirect from www.domain.com to domain.com or vise versa. Otherwise either request would point to content and resolve correctly but maintain the original URI.

Answer (score 0):

You need two different CloudFront distributions.

1. `example.com` -> s3 origin
2. `www.example.com` -> s3 redirect bucket (website) to `example.com`

Comment: this doesnt work when I try to access `https://www.example.com`